# Issue with Groovy language converting Integers to Roman numerals

Tags: groovy, integer, roman-numerals, groovy-console

Here is the output that I get, It should be converting to Roman Numerals - the following - 3569 and 1234

Number: 3569 1000: III
100: V
10: VI
1: IX

Number: 1234 1000: I
100: II
10: III
1: IV

Here is the code:

```
def emitRNValue(int quotient, int divisor) { 
Map strokes = [1000:['M'],
                500:['D'], 
                100:['C'],
                 50:['L'],
                 10:['X'],
                  5:['V'], 
                  1:['I']] 


//def Closure c = { println "$it: ${emitRNValue[qoutient-1]}"  } 
//(divisor).each (c) 

def RNList = ['I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X']
(divisor).each { println "$it: ${RNList[quotient-1]}"}



//(1..1000).each (c) 
// Yes a switch statement works here.

}
 
def processNumber(int n) { 
    print "Number: ${n} " 
    int divisor = 1000 
    while (n > 0) { 
    // need integer division here 
       int quotient = n.intdiv(divisor) 
       emitRNValue(quotient,divisor) 
     //  println "divisor:  ${divisor} quotient ${quotient}" 
   //  now make the number and divisor smaller 
       n = n - quotient * divisor 
       divisor = divisor.intdiv(10) 
    } 
    println() 
} 
// body of script 
   processNumber(3569) 
   processNumber(1234)
```

Comment: which part doesn't work?

Comment: The roman numeral conversion is incorrect unfortunately @OnnoRouast

Comment: Which part is incorrect? It worked fine when I checked! Could you add to the description a list of example `input + expected output` pairs, so that we know what is expected? Thanks!